# Return Task<int> from int member C# best practice

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a member of type int in my class.
I would like to expose the class with a Task function that return this member.

```
int _someMember;
```

I know i can do:

```
public int ReturnTheMember() { return _someMember; }
```

But all my class function must be Task based.

Is it possible to wrap this call in a task ? something like:

```
    public async Task<int> ReturnTheMember()
    {
        await Task.FromResult(0);
        return _someMember;
    }
```

Notice - I must do Task.FromResult(0) because i treat warning as errors - this wont compile since method with async on signature must contain "await".

I would like to know if this is a good pattern i used. Or this is wrong doing so.

Comment: This is a ridiculous idea. Why do you need it to return a `Task<int>` if the result is available ***immediately***?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: Probably to satisfy an interface.

Comment: this is SDK, all my SDK calls must be async by design. right now i return it immediately, but a week from now i might go to some SQL database and pull the int from there.. i dont want to block my dear sdk consumer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `async` at all.

Just create a normal method and call `Task.FromResult()` to create a synchronously-resolved task with your result.

Comment: To be clear: `public Task<int> ReturnTheMember() { return Task.FromResult(_someMember); }`

Comment: @StephenCleary indeed.